# Wordpress paginate_links returns same 10 pages

Tags: wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type

I have the following code where the issue is that the paginate_links returns the same 10 results when clicking on next. The url changes and I can see it calculates the correct pagination so It knows which posts(events) are there. Is there something I need to parse into the paginate_links array so it knows it is the event posts it is dealing with?

```
<?php

 $today = date('Ymd');
          $wp_query = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'event',
            'meta_key' => 'event_date',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'nopaging' => false,
            'meta_query' => array(
              array(
                'key' => 'event_date',
                'compare' => '>=',
                'value' => $today,
                'type' => 'numeric'
              )
            )
          ));
while($wp_query->have_posts()) {
            $wp_query->the_post();
            ?>
              <div class="event-summary">
                <a class="event-summary__date" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                
                <span class="event-summary__day"><?php
                $eventDate = new DateTime(get_field('event_date'));
                echo $eventDate->format('d') ?></span>  
                <span class="event-summary__month"><?php echo $eventDate->format('M') ?></span>    
                <span class="event-summary__year"><?php echo $eventDate->format('Y') ?></span>    
                </a>
                <div class="event-summary__content">
                <h5 class="event-summary__title headline headline--tiny"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
                <p class="event-summary__excerpt"><?php if (has_excerpt()) {
                    echo get_the_excerpt();
                    } else {
                    echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 18);
                    } ?> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="">Læs mere</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
          <?php
    }

echo paginate_links(array(
        'prev_text' => '<span>« Previous</span>',
        'next_text' => '<span>Next »</span>'
      
      ));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for the query to show the next page you'll need to include the current page index to the query with the `paged` key. This will change when you go to the next page, effectively showing the next x amount of posts.

It's also a good idea to include the `posts_per_page` to indicate *when* the next page is available.

```php
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? (int) get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$wp_query = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_type'      => 'event',
  'paged'          => $paged,
  'posts_per_page' => 5,
  'meta_key'       => 'event_date',
  'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
  'order'          => 'ASC',
  'nopaging'       => false,
  'meta_query'     => array(
    array(
      'key'     => 'event_date',
      'compare' => '>=',
      'value'   => $today,
      'type'    => 'numeric'
    )
  )
));
```